# Use values and not labels when manipulating datasets in R's data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

So I have been trying to manipulate a dataset using `data.table`. Like in `STATA`, I wanted to categorise my factors using their values and not labels. I feel this is much safer for when working with categorical variables that have very strange labels with lots of spaces.

So far I have not been able to do this in `R`. Is this even possible or am I missing something?

I have attached a dummy code to recreate this issue.

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

classmates
# dummy data 
school_friends <-data.table(names = as.factor(c("Beth", "Ben", "Andrew","Amy", "Claire","Ahmed", "Moses", "Jose", "Ibrahim", "Rachel")
                                              ), 
                            age = c(19,18,19,19,20,19,19,17,18,19))
                        
str(school_friends)

# categorise dataset
school_friends[names==1 | 
               names==4 |
               names==5 |
               names==10,
               sex:=1]

school_friends[names==2 |
               names==3 |
               names==6 |
               names==7 |
               names==8 |
               names==9,
               sex:=2]
# labels levels
school_friends$sex <- factor(school_friends$sex, levels = c(1,2), 
                             labels = c("Boy", "Girl"))
```

In `STATA` doing this would be as straight forward as this:

```
# create new categories 
gen sex=.
replace sex=0 if names==1 | names==4 | names==5 | names==10
replace sex=1 if names==2 | names==3 | names==6 | names==7 | names==8 | names==9 
# label categories 
label define edulab 0 "Boy" 1 "Girl"
label values edu edulab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way would be to use the levels function like this:

```
school_friends[names%in%levels(school_friends$names)[1:2],sex:=1]
```